# How to show full text on mouseenter using jquery?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, mouseevent

I have a string like "mouseenter I will be displayed" assigned to one var. But I want display user only "mouseenter I will be disp..." and entire text on mouseenter via dialog or popup info. string is dynamic it will get change on different scenario. also on mousedown dialog should hide.

**EDIT:**

javascript

```
var orignalData = 'i am complete text'
if(orignalData.length){
incompleteData = orignalData.substring(0,5)
incompleteData += '...'
alert(incompleteData)
}
var div = document.getElementById('divID');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + incompleteData;
```

once now user mouseenter on "i am ..." I want to display a small popup with displaying entire thing and once user remove mouse from "i am ..." the popup will be hide or removed.

Comment: Share the code please

Comment: @ZI3n please check edit

Comment: Modal should be better than popup, because browsers may block them

Comment: any way it show entire text

Comment: I'll try, but I only know jquery syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am a little bit too "creative" here, or do not understand - but do you in fact not just want a `<div>` with `text-overflow: ellipsis` you dynamically can assign both text and hint (title) to? If you have a `<div>` :

```html
<div id="divID"></div>
```

and the CSS :

```css
#divID {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and finally assigning the content through JS, you will get the desired result (I suppose) :

```js
var originalData = 'i am complete text'
var div = document.getElementById('divID');
div.innerText = originalData;
div.title = originalData;
```

demonstration -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2rvzn2qn/**

Comment: $('#subTitle').append("<p style='margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;line-height:0px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;max-width: 200px;white-space: nowrap;'>("+dimensionField+")</p>"); is this correct because its not getting displayed value

Comment: @SohamShetty, you have `line-height:0px` - is this by intent? It makes the appended `<p>` invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I let my jquery version because, as I told you, I don't know the javascript syntax.

First, the HTML :

```
<p class="text"></p>
<div id="dialog">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Then the JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var orignalData = 'i am complete text';

    if (orignalData.length) {
        var incompleteData = orignalData.substring(0,5);
        incompleteData += '...';
        $('.text').text(incompleteData);
    }

    $('.text').hover(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            open: function() {
                $(this).html(orignalData);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zlen/g1j7enf1/) example, there isn't the css for the dialog. I let you see that